# Multiple Deselection of rows in datagrid is not working with ItemRenderers in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I have an advanced datagrid.I used itemrenderers for each cell to display text with image.Now when i try to do multiple selection of rows using ctrl key its working fine but when i try do the deselection by using the ctrl key on the selected row all selected items are getting deselected and only the one which i clicked is highlighting.This is not the right behaviour when compared to the datagrid multi selection of rows without itemrenderers.When i click on non itemrenderer cells deselection of rows is working perfectly where as deselection of rows with itemrender are not working as expected.Can any one pls tell me how to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a "non itemrenderer": every cell is an ItemRenderer. Assuming you mean that it doesn't work correctly with your custom ItemRenderer, you should show us its code.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for the problem.I used itemrenderer along with itemeditor and activated edit after double click. when we select multiple rows with ctrl and deselect each item its not working because of itemeditor. so i checked if ctrl key is pressed then i made datagrid.editable to false else i made editable to true. Now i am able to do deselection of rows perfectly.